# ArcGIS Arcade Expression: Data from a Service Query

Tags: arcgis-online, query, arcade

This maybe not be possible but trying anyway. I have a Map Service with geometry features published. Two of the columns are 'Zone1' and 'Zone2' with values like 'ABC' or 'DEF'. The values of 'ABC' or 'DEF' can be present in both columns in the same row.

There is also a static 'lookup table' with a column named ZONECLASS and values like 'ABC' or 'DEF'. The static table is also published as layer in the along with the layer with geometry. So far so good.

What I am trying to do is that inside ArcGIS Online's Arcade Expression, query the static table's layer and get that data displayed inside ArcGIS Online. The query works in the browser as:

http://servicepath/MapServer/1/query?where=ZONECLASS=%ABC27&outFields=DOCNAME

But how to bring value of the DOCNAME field inside ArcGIS Online? I have built an expression as above url but that's just a string. I need to get the output.

Is that possible or do I need to seek an alternative solution?

Comment: May be wrong but current arcade functions are limited to the row level. Cannot get related or make web calls.. Would have to post process using trigger, goeEvent or batch script.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you can use [FeatureSetBy*](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/data_functions/#featuresetbyname) to get a reference to the lookup table and obtain the value you are interested from the other table through that reference.

This functionality was added around pro 2.3.